# MonoTouch Resources

Tags: c#, iphone, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I want use a images for buttons, background in interface builder. The problem is when I add the files to my project in MonoDevelop the images don't appear in interface builder. Could someone please tell me where to put the images so that they appear in interface builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They won't show up in IB, you have to type out the path manually.

After you put an image in the first time in IB, if you reuse it, it will start showing up.  But even then, it can only do this within the same XIB file.

MonoDevelop is lacking slightly in some places where it needs to communicate with IB, it does a good job going the other way--or reacting to IB's changes, however.

Comment: This is unacceptable Novel should fix the problem immediately. I mean it costs a lot more to use monoTouch instead of just plain Xcode (How does that work?).

Comment: There is probably good reason Novell hasn't gotten this feature to work yet.  And I believe the productivity increase by using C# is well worth the price.  My company has probably reused 1000's of lines of desktop C# code, can't imagine the development cost for that in Objective-C.  Is it really that bad to type a file path?  Can't imagine you would use that many images in an app, if you take advantage of the built in controls in UIKit that are already pretty aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Using ImageView as an example, there is an Image setting in IB.  So if you have an image in your project named MyPic.png in a folder named Images, you just fill out "Images/MyPic.png".  You also have to set the build action to "Content" on the picture in your project.  Otherwise the picture isn't copied to the device.

Comment: Thanks I got it working but I would really love to see the image in IB.

Comment: Miguel de Icaza confirmed on twitter that they're working on that feature for the next version of MonoTouch that will work with XCode 4. Personally though, I would say that if you're depending that much on XCode so that showing some images is such a big deal, you're may be just doing it wrong.

Comment: This all works properly now in Xamarin.iOS - you use Build Option "Bundle Resource" and put all your images in a "Resource" subdirectory in your C# project.